# Is CVS to Gitlab migration corrupt any jars under any repository using cvs2git

Tags: cvs2git, git-fast-import

I want to migrate CVS repositories into Gitlab. I have multiple modules under a repository and few modules have multiple jars in it. I used the cvs2git tool to migrate this, it's migrated without any issues but I couldn't compile the repository after migration because few jars getting corrupted. Why it's getting corrupted?

While compilation the builds are failing, I just checked the jars which was getting corrupted,

```
jar -tvf ./<path>/<myjar>.jar
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:120)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:1115)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:293)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)
```

My jars in CVS as well as in GIT after migration as follows,

**GIT**

```
[root@test myrepo]# ls -ltr ./<path>/isorelax-20030108.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 192232 Sep 27 16:54 ./<path>/isorelax-20030108.jar
[root@test myrepo]# ls -ltr ./<path>/opt/isorelax-20030108.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 192232 Sep 27 16:54 ./<path>/opt/isorelax-20030108.jar
```

**CVS**

```
[root@test myrepo]# ls -ltr ./<path>/isorelax-20030108.jar
-rwxr-x--- 1 root root 192743 Jun 10  2015 ./<path>/isorelax-20030108.jar

[root@test myrepo]# ls -ltr ./<path>/opt/isorelax-20030108.jar    
-rw-r----- 1 root root 192602 Jun 30  2015 ./<path>/opt/isorelax-20030108.jar
```

We are accessing **./opt/isorelax-20030108.jar** jar while compiling but getting failed in GIT but CVS builds successfully.

I ran the CVS status on the jars one is showing with -kb but another one is not.

```
[root@test myrepo]# cvs status ./<path>/isorelax-20030108.jar

=============================================================
File: isorelax-20030108.jar     Status: Up-to-date

   Working revision:    1.2.1
   Repository revision: 1.2.1 /cvs/myrepo/<path>/isorelax-20030108.jar,v
   Sticky Tag:          TAG_1 (revision: 1.2.1)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      (none)


[root@test myrepo]# cvs status ./<path>/opt/isorelax-20030108.jar

=================================================================
File: isorelax-20030108.jar     Status: Up-to-date

   Working revision:    1.2.3
   Repository revision: 1.2.3 /cvs/myrepo/<path>/opt/isorelax-20030108.jar,v
   Sticky Tag:          TAG_1 (revision: 1.2.3)
   Sticky Date:         (none)
   Sticky Options:      -kb
```

We are accessing the jars with **Sticky Options: -kb**, still it's failing...

What was the problem here? Kindly provide your thoughts on this.

Comment: Are the jars marked with keyword=binary in the cvs repository?

Comment: How can I find the jars marked with keyword=binary in CVS repository?

Comment: @Mort If I run the following command returns the following,
 "file myjar.jar" ------>
myjar.jar: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract

Comment: @Mort Kindly confirm that they are pushed as binary, what is the problem here?

Comment: In the CVS repo, if you type `cvs status myjar.jar` it should indicate that the file is binary with `Sticky Options: -kb`. If it is not, you probably need to set it in CVS and re-import to git. https://www.gnu.org/software/trans-coord/manual/cvs/html_node/Binary-howto.html

Comment: Thank you @Mort. It's showing the cvs status of the jar. I will check and update you.

Comment: @Mort The jars are present with Sticky Options: -kb. But still why am I getting corrupted jars during migration. Kindly provide your thoughts on this.

Comment: I am out of ideas then. Sorry. I would try some binary comparisons of equivalent versions in `cvs` vs `git` and see what the byte-level differences are then use your programming and cvs and git experience to create a hypothesis from there.

Comment: @Mort I have updated the question with byte-level differences. Kindly check and provide your thoughts on this.

Comment: `jar`s are essentially zip files, can you confirm that you can uncompress them with a regular decompression tool? If that is the case, it is unlikely a byte-to-byte difference. Based on the error you get, it looks like that some paths have changed during the conversion. can't you re-create your `jar`s from the sources in `git` instead of using the `cvs` ones?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply @norok2! 
No, I can't re-create, I just need to migrate from CVS to GITLAB.

Comment: @SST by byte-level differences I mean figure out which exact bytes in the files are different, not the sizes, the exact bytes. Look at them with your computer science mind on and figure out if you see a pattern (e.g. CR->CRLF, or anything else).

Comment: Ok. I will check and update you.

Comment: @SST did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Mort The Jar files are getting corrupted while migration I am not sure, what's happening while migration. :(